# Chart is not populating when getting the data from AJAX call

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I have this very annoying problem and I feel I have an idea why it is caused but cannot for the life of me get it fixed. Maybe it's because I don't know a fundamental rule of programming....

So let me demonstrate the issue:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="angularApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Wall</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div ng-controller="wallPosts">
                    <div class="panel panel-default post" ng-repeat="post in posts">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options">
                            </canvas> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- col-md-8 end -->
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/jsLib/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/jsLib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/angularApp.js"></script> 
    <script src="/jsLib/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/jsLib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Angular Controller:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', ['chart.js']);

angularApp.controller('wallPosts', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.labels = ["Agree", "Disagree"];
    $scope.data = [];

    $http.get('/api/posts')
        .success(function(res){
            $scope.posts = res.posts;
            //$scope.data = [100, 500];
            $scope.data = [res.posts.agreeCounter, res.posts.disagreeCounter];
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
        });
}]);
```

The API response looks like this:

```
"posts": [
        {
            "postID": "postID1233",
            "title": "testTitle",
            "description": "testDescription",
            "agreeCounter": 100,
            "disagreeCounter": 50
        }]
```

The problem is that the "canvas" seems to be getting generated right-away without the data I am passing through. When I pass the $scope.data as [100, 50] (statically), it works.

By the way, the res.posts works as I have tested that with post.title, post.description etc (it also has post.agreeCounter) so that is not the issue.

So how do I go about sorting this out? Any input will help.

Thanks again,
Shayan

Comment: Could you plz add JSON comming from server? What type does `typeof res.posts.agreeCounter` print?

Comment: The data comes back as null. res.posts works because I have used res.title, res.description but when I use it for the canvas, it doesn't work.

Anyhow, I have updated the original post with the response. Thanks for having a look

Comment: If the data is `null` how do you expect your chart to work? :)

Comment: That actually is my question. Why is it null? I will explore the answer below and update you all.

Comment: Actually it is not `null` but `undefined`. Because `posts` is an array. It doesn't have say `agreeCounter` property. Each element has one. But array doesn't.

Comment: Actually it was null when I was looking at it. Somehow it was not coming through at all. Anyhow, the issue is fixed now. See the accepted answer below. Thanks for taking the time to comment bud!

Comment: Just realised you are the same guy who gave the answer lol. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need a chart for every post, right?

Change your template to get data for every post

```
<div class="panel panel-default post" ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <canvas class="chart chart-pie" 
            chart-data="post.data"
            chart-labels="labels"
            chart-options="options"
        ></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And populate `post.data` for each incomming post

```
 $http.get('/api/posts')
   .success(function(res) {
     $scope.posts = res.posts;

     // populate post.data
     $scope.posts.forEach(function(post) {
        post.data = [post.agreeCounter, post.disagreeCounter];
     });
   })
```

BTW IDs **must be unique** within document. You shouldn't use static id (`id="pie"`) inside `ng-repeat`. It will generate multiple nodes with the same id.

Comment: That worked! I still have to understand how it worked so will dig into that. Also, the id is supposed to be the same as I will be using a CSS on it but that is not the issue here. Thanks a million man! You saved my life

Comment: @ShayanKhan You should use class instead of id if you have multiple elements to apply css to. Actually you already have say `chart-pie`.

Comment: Okay wicked. New to this whole thing (after 10 years in fact) so started from scratch and worked from Node + MongoDB and now onto front-end. Thanks again mate!